# Remove existing code side of div code

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Goal:
If there are any html syntax code or data inside of

```
<div id="feedEntries"></div>
```

Then everything should be removed and be contained empty only.

Problem:
What syntax do I need in order to remove every code and data inside of

```
<div id="feedEntries"></div>
```

Please remember that i don't want to add any class or id inside of "feedEntries"

---

```
        <h3>Search</h3>
        <div class="content">
            <form>
                <input type="text" width="15" value="searchword" id="searchTermTextField"><input type="button" name="some_name" value="Sök" id="searchButton">              
            </form>
            <div id="feedEntries">

            </div>
        </div>
```

---

```
function fetchSearchResults(json) {

    var feedEntriesDivElement = document.getElementById('feedEntries'); 
    var ulElement = document.createElement('ul');



    if (feedEntriesDivElement.children.length >= 0)
    {
        // Syntax code to remove the code/data  



        }



    for (var i = 0; i < json.responseData.results.length; i++)
    {
        var liElement = document.createElement('li');       
        var personText = document.createTextNode(json.responseData.results[i].titleNoFormatting);
        var newlink = document.createElement('a'); 
        newlink.setAttribute('href', json.responseData.results[i].url );        

        newlink.appendChild(personText);
        liElement.appendChild(newlink);
        ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
    }

    feedEntriesDivElement.appendChild(ulElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure DOM and Javascript (sometimes considered better than altering innerHTML):

```
if ( feedEntriesDivElement.hasChildNodes() )
{
    while ( feedEntriesDivElement.childNodes.length >= 1 )
    {
        feedEntriesDivElement.removeChild( feedEntriesDivElement.firstChild );       
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`feedEntriesDivElement.innerHTML = '';` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery like this `$('#feedEntries').empty()`

to remove from javascript please check the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683366/remove-all-the-children-dom-elements-in-div)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementByIf('feedEntries').innerHTML = ''
```