# in javascript dom, removing all children yields error

Tags: javascript, dom

using standard routine to remove all children in element

```
while( el.lastChild ) el.removeChild( el.lastChild );
```

yields: Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

```
for( var i=el.children.length; i; i-- ) el.removeChild( el.children[i-1] );
```

yields same

routine works 99% of the time, but in one DIV errors out.

if it matters, focus is not in DIV.

any idea how to proceed?

---

Found problem.

On new code for INPUT type='number' where `input` and `mouseout` events created a `change` event so field would update correctly.

In some instances updating the item meant removing the row.

The problem was that, once the row was removed, the INPUT's focus was lost, thereby generating its own `change` event.  When this event ran the row was still existent, but had lost the relationship to its parent.  This generated the DOM Error 8 - not found.

Again, we have met the enemy, and they is us (thank you Pogo).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all the children DOM elements in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683366/remove-all-the-children-dom-elements-in-div)

Comment: This should work, so it would help if you could write which browser you are using and maybe provide a small example of HTML code you are using it on.

Comment: @Tomalak - same algorithm, but nasty results

Comment: @Wladimir Palant - chrome.  getting incompatibilities fixed for ff testing now.

Comment: I tried the bookmarklet `javascript:var el = document.body;while( el.lastChild ) el.removeChild( el.lastChild );void(0)` on a few websites in Chrome and it works fine. So it must be something related to your particular webpage.

Comment: @Wladimir - I agree!  this code has been working without problem for months.  that it should suddenly fail to me is totally bizarre.  Right now I'm eliminating HTML piece by piece to see if I can find one piece that breaks it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was triggers attempting to remove the row once an earlier trigger had already removed it.  See description at bottom of question