# Remove all divs from in a parent div

Tags: javascript

Hey how do I remove all divs from a parent div in JavaScript?

I can't find non jquery examples. They all have different classes/Ids so I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do it ? For example:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div class="something"      id="one">Remove me</div>
   <div class="something_two"  id="two">Remove me</div>
   <div class="something_three"id="three">Remove me</div>
   <div class="something_four" id="four">Remove me</div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to do this - my current method is to do `innerHTML = "";` but wondered if thats only best for removing text and not elements?

Comment: `innerHTML` is for everything, `innerText` is for text (not sure where it works) `innerHTML` is way faster then standard DOM methods, I mean performance.

Comment: I was told there was a more preferred way to `innerHTML` I've never know why though.

Comment: see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683366/remove-all-the-children-dom-elements-in-div

Comment: yes, because `innerHTML` is not a standard but is faster so its more preferable in fact. Anyway it's better to use some library to handle DOM manipulation.

Comment: I don't see how a library like jQuery is any better i don't like to use such libraries prefer to make my own from ground up! :)

Comment: it's just way easier to work with high level API and be sure it works in many browsers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `innerHTML` *will* remove actual elements, [there are some cross browser quirks](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html) (mainly IE which, ironically, was the one that originally invented `innerHTML`).

Here's a more standard way of doing it:

```
var el = document.getElementById('parent');

while ( el.firstChild ) el.removeChild( el.firstChild );
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way seems to be:

```
document.getElementById('parent').textContent = '';
```