# Function Call, Delay, Then Function Call again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a code with a 2 step function to rewrite navlinks. I have the remove links function, then the function that adds 1 set of links, then another button doing the same thing but with different links. This is what I have. (HTML with the components in 1)

```js
        function execFunction() {
          removeLinks();
          linksAddSet1();
        }

        function execFunction2() {
          removeLinks();
          linksAddSet2();
        }

        function removeLinks() {
          var list = document.getElementById("output2");
          list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
          list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
          list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
          list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
          list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
          list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
        }

        function linksAddSet1() {
          var out = document.getElementById("output2");
          var args = ["About", "Games", "The Hideout", "Staff", "Donate", "Contact Us", ];

          function displayMenu() {
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            ul.className = "mainMenu";
            args.forEach(function(name, index) {
              var li = document.createElement('li'),
                an = document.createElement('a');
              li.className = "mmenu-item-" + index;
              li.setAttribute = "link rel", "stylesheet", "type", "text/css", "href", "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/style.css";
              an.innerHTML = name;
              an.setAttribute('href', "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/" + name + ".html");
              li.appendChild(an);
              ul.appendChild(li);
            });
            out.appendChild(ul);
          }
          if (output2.childNodes.length > 0) {} else {
            displayMenu();
          }
        }

        function linksAddSet2() {
          var list = document.getElementById("output2");
          var out = document.getElementById("output2");
          var args = ["Tools", "Tutorials"];

          function displayMenu() {
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            ul.className = "mainMenu";
            args.forEach(function(name, index) {
              var li = document.createElement('li'),
                an = document.createElement('a');
              li.className = "mmenu-item-" + index;
              li.setAttribute = "link rel", "stylesheet", "type", "text/css", "href", "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/style.css";
              an.innerHTML = name;
              an.setAttribute('href', "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/" + name + ".html");
              li.appendChild(an);
              ul.appendChild(li);
            });
            out.appendChild(ul);
          }
          if (output2.childNodes.length > 0) {} else {
            displayMenu();
          }
        }
```

```css
        #navigation {
          width: 760px;
          height: 35px;
          position: absolute;
          border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
          background: orange;
          padding: 0px;
        }
        #navigation .padding {
          padding: 2px;
        }
        #navigation .navlinks {
          position: absolute;
          top: 1px;
          left: 0px;
        }
        #navigation .navlinks ul {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
          text-align: center;
          list-style-type: none;
          width: 760px;
          height: 35px;
        }
        #navigation .navlinks li {
          position: relative;
          top: 5px;
          margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
          list-style-type: none;
          display: inline;
        }
        #navigation .navlinks li a {
          color: #000000;
          padding: 5px 0px 9px 0px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 18px;
          font-family: karmatic_arcaderegular;
          padding: 5px 0px 9px 0px;
        }
        #navigation .navlinks li a:hover {
          margin: 0px;
          color: #ffffff;
          background: orange;
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="navlinks">
    <div id="output2">
      <ul class="mainMenu">
        <li class="mmenu-item-0">
          <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/About.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mmenu-item-1">
          <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/Games.html">Games</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mmenu-item-2">
          <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/The Hideout.html">The Hideout</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mmenu-item-3">
          <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/Staff.html">Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mmenu-item-4">
          <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/Donate.html">Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mmenu-item-5">
          <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="removeLinks()">Remove Links</button>
  <button onclick="execFunction()">Link Set 1</button>
  <button onclick="execFunction2()">Link Set 2</button>
```

The `execFunction()` and `execFunction2()` is what breaks it. I have it so that the when Link Set 1 is clicked, it executes `execFunction()`, which should execute the `removeLinks()` function, then add the links with the following `linksAddSet1()` or `linksAddSet2()`. But it doesn't seem to have a delay, which makes both functions run at the same time, causing it to either disfunction or have the links create instantly then have the `removeLinks()` function remove both of them. Any way to set a "delay" between the two function calls that can have them both execute safely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I do if I want a JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: Can you make this in to a JSFiddle, please?

Comment: Note that it's impossible for the two functions to "run at the same time" - JavaScript is inherently single threaded, and any block of code / event handler will run to completion before the next one begins.

Comment: @gvee It's now in a snippet. @ Bijan I'll keep note. @ James Thorpe Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a delay. What you were trying is fine when executed in a sequence. There was a script error in your `removeLinks` function. I had it fixed and it works as expected. See **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79wLw0m2/)**

```
function removeLinks() {
    var list = document.getElementById("output2");
    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/683429/297641
    while (list.hasChildNodes()) {
        list.removeChild(list.lastChild);
    }
}
```

### Code Snippet

```js
function execFunction() {
    removeLinks();
    linksAddSet1();
}

function execFunction2() {
    removeLinks();
    linksAddSet2();
}

function removeLinks() {
    var list = document.getElementById("output2");
    while (list.hasChildNodes()) {
        list.removeChild(list.lastChild);
    }
}

function linksAddSet1() {
    var out = document.getElementById("output2");
    var args = ["About", "Games", "The Hideout", "Staff", "Donate", "Contact Us", ];

    function displayMenu() {
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.className = "mainMenu";
        args.forEach(function (name, index) {
            var li = document.createElement('li'),
                an = document.createElement('a');
            li.className = "mmenu-item-" + index;
            li.setAttribute = "link rel", "stylesheet", "type", "text/css", "href", "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/style.css";
            an.innerHTML = name;
            an.setAttribute('href', "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/" + name + ".html");
            li.appendChild(an);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        });
        out.appendChild(ul);
    }
    if (output2.childNodes.length > 0) {} else {
        displayMenu();
    }
}

function linksAddSet2() {
    var list = document.getElementById("output2");
    var out = document.getElementById("output2");
    var args = ["Tools", "Tutorials"];

    function displayMenu() {
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.className = "mainMenu";
        args.forEach(function (name, index) {
            var li = document.createElement('li'),
                an = document.createElement('a');
            li.className = "mmenu-item-" + index;
            li.setAttribute = "link rel", "stylesheet", "type", "text/css", "href", "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/style.css";
            an.innerHTML = name;
            an.setAttribute('href', "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/" + name + ".html");
            li.appendChild(an);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        });
        out.appendChild(ul);
    }
    if (output2.childNodes.length > 0) {} else {
        displayMenu();
    }
}
```

```css
#navigation {
    width: 760px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    background: orange;
    padding: 0px;
}
#navigation .padding {
    padding: 2px;
}
#navigation .navlinks {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 0px;
}
#navigation .navlinks ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 760px;
    height: 35px;
}
#navigation .navlinks li {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#navigation .navlinks li a {
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px 0px 9px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: karmatic_arcaderegular;
    padding: 5px 0px 9px 0px;
}
#navigation .navlinks li a:hover {
    margin: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: orange;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="navlinks">
        <div id="output2">
            <ul class="mainMenu">
                <li class="mmenu-item-0"> <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/About.html">About</a>

                </li>
                <li class="mmenu-item-1"> <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/Games.html">Games</a>

                </li>
                <li class="mmenu-item-2"> <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/The Hideout.html">The Hideout</a>

                </li>
                <li class="mmenu-item-3"> <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/Staff.html">Staff</a>

                </li>
                <li class="mmenu-item-4"> <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/Donate.html">Donate</a>

                </li>
                <li class="mmenu-item-5"> <a href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="removeLinks()">Remove Links</button>
    <button onclick="execFunction()">Link Set 1</button>
    <button onclick="execFunction2()">Link Set 2</button>
```